# Unbalanced Parenthesis and Missing Operator

Tags: windows, batch-file

Following is a batch file which calls another batch file inside for loop which loops all the txt files of the current folder.

```
@
echo off
setlocal
for % % i in ( * .txt) do(
    callSingle.bat -if = % % i - of = % ~dp0
)
endlocal@ 
echo on
```

The single bat file is following
It is writing to the log file for each execution.
After the execution at the command prompt showing

```
Unbalanced Parenthesis.
Unbalanced Parenthesis.
Missing Operator.
```

When opened log file shows Start Time and end time are correct. But the duration is wrong getting

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo ************************************************************************** > %2.log
echo *                     Log File for %2                             * >> %2.log
echo ************************************************************************** >> %2.log
rem The format of %TIME% is HH:MM:SS,CS for example 23:59:59,99
set STARTTIME=%TIME%

rem here begins the command you want to measure
some_executable.exe -if=%2 -of=%4
rem here ends the command you want to measure

set ENDTIME=%TIME%

rem output as time
echo STARTTIME: %STARTTIME% >> %2.log
echo ENDTIME: %ENDTIME% >> %2.log

rem calculating the duratyion is easy
rem set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%

rem convert STARTTIME and ENDTIME to milliseconds
set /A STARTTIME=(10%STARTTIME:~0,2%-1000)*3600000 + (10%STARTTIME:~3,2%-1000)*60000 + (10%STARTTIME:~6,2%-1000)*1000 + (10%STARTTIME:~9,2%-1000)
set /A ENDTIME=(10%ENDTIME:~0,2%-1000)*3600000 + (10%ENDTIME:~3,2%-1000)*60000 + (10%ENDTIME:~6,2%-1000)*1000 + (10%ENDTIME:~9,2%-1000)

rem calculating the duratyion is easy
set /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%

rem we might have measured the time inbetween days
if %ENDTIME% LSS %STARTTIME% set /A DURATION=%STARTTIME%-%ENDTIME%

rem now break the milliseconds down to hors, minutes, seconds and the remaining milliseconds
set /A DURATIONH=%DURATION% / 3600000
set /A DURATIONM=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*3600000) / 60000
set /A DURATIONS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*3600000 - %DURATIONM%*60000) / 1000
set /A DURATIONHS=(%DURATION% - %DURATIONH%*3600000 - %DURATIONM%*60000 - %DURATIONS%*1000)

rem some formatting
if %DURATIONH% LSS 10 set DURATIONH=0%DURATIONH%
if %DURATIONM% LSS 10 set DURATIONM=0%DURATIONM%
if %DURATIONS% LSS 10 set DURATIONS=0%DURATIONS%
if %DURATIONHS% LSS 10 set DURATIONHS=0%DURATIONHS%

echo DURATION: %DURATIONH%:%DURATIONM%:%DURATIONS%.%DURATIONHS% >> %2.log


endlocal
goto :EOF
```

This issue happens some times or else it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **general** debugging **advice**: `echo ON` to see where and why an error appears. Add some `pause`...

Your first batch file code is totally messed up, please correct it.

*The format of `%TIME%` is `HH:MM:SS,CS` for example `23:59:59,99`*, but `echo "%TIME%"` issued *ante meridiem* returns (for example) `" 1:09:24,46"`: **note leading space**. Hence, use

```
set "STARTTIME=%TIME: =0%"
```

and

```
set "ENDTIME=%TIME: =0%"
```

See [this script repository on date and time arithmetic](http://www.commandline.co.uk/lib/treeview/index.php).